# How to add multiple ImageView's inside of LinearLayout using code behind

Tags: java, android

[image]

I need to create something like that, a Container with 8 ImageView's and be able to get each of then, I already have the code to take the image at the gallery, but I'm stuck on that, my current code I have this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Activity :

```
linearImages = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearImages);
Test = new ImageView(this);
galleryIntent(){.......
Test.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
linearImages.addView(Test);
```

But only works with two Images!

Comment: maibe there is just no space for more images in layout?

Comment: how can I workthrought? at first i was adding 8 imageviews but its not the right way to do

Comment: how exactly you want to place images in the layout if only 2 of them fit it? You have to decide it by yourself.

Comment: that's the problem, I don't know how to do, I want to increase the image as long the user is going to select the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

in your layout:

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/image_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gallery_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

now for adding use:

```
  for (final GalleryItem item : items) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                            , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     param.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
     iv.setLayoutParams(param);
     iv.setImageBitmap(item);
     iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
     layout.add(iv);   //your gallery layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `HorizontalScrollView` to `ScrollView`

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `LayoutParams`:

```
Image.setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

then, add your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater  layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                         context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
yourLinerarLayout.add(view);
```

Here, `R.layout.control` is `xml` file in your layout folder that contain view of single piece of view add whatever time you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TableRow` and take array of `ImageViews`. Pass this `ImageViews` in to `TableView`, then pass final `TableView` in to `LinearLayout`.

Some thing like this:

```
 TableRow row = new TableRow(mContext);
 final ImageView[] myTextViews = new ImageView[n];
```

Also, to get call back for each `ImageView` use `setTag` and `getTag` functions.